# Is this how ATM and SONET work?

Tags: internet, fiber, mpls, wan, atm

This is how I visualize how SONET carry ATM, and how ATM carry IP:

[image]

Is my visualization correct?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that i would advise changing is that SONET devices are not 'switches' They do not decapsulate or encapsulate at layer-2. They put received frames into containers and transmit them within the configured time slot along a pre-determined path, that does not change.
Normally they would be referred to as 'SONET ring' or layer-1 path.